# Autowiring bean based on command line arguement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring framework. Using it to develop a java command line program with assistance with lombok library.

I'm trying to create my bean based on the value being passed via command line argument, which at this point fails.

Running the application via command line with args: `java -jar TestProject.jar -Dfield="TEMP"`

Any suggestion would be helpful.  Thanks.

**Main class**

```
public class TestApp implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private DataService dataService;

/**
 *
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    System.out.println("STOPPING ******");
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

    this.dataService.processFile();
 }
}
```

**DataService class (works fine)**

```
@Component
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {


@Autowired(required = false)
private Processor processor;

/**
 * Processes file and returns results
 *
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
@Override
public void processFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    if (processor != null) {
        System.out.println(this.processor.getClass());
        List<Long> values = processor.roundUp();

        String strDisplay = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(strDisplay)) {
                strDisplay = "" + values.get(i);
            } else {
                strDisplay = strDisplay + "," + values.get(i);
            }
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(strDisplay)) {
            System.out.println(strDisplay);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Testing");
        }
    }
 }
```

}

**Processor (abstract class)**

```
public abstract class Processor {

@Autowired
public FileParser fileParser;

public abstract List<String> process();

public List<Long> roundUp() {
    List<String> valueList = process();
    List<Long> valueListDouble = new ArrayList<>();
    if (valueList != null) {
        for (String value : valueList) {
            valueListDouble.add(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(value)));
        }
    }
    return valueListDouble;

  }
 }
```

**TempProcessorImpl class**, to be created based on command line argument

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{systemProperties['field']!=null && systemProperties['field'].equals('TEMP')}")
public class TempProcessorImpl extends Processor {

@Override
public List<String> process() {
    return fileParser.getColumnValuesForHeaderFromFile();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSystemResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-filesystemresource) and ConfigurationProperties if you want to get a path to a file from an [external location](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) (i.e. from command-line arguments). It is a good approach to create a config class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

  private FileSystemResource file;

  public FileSystemResource getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(FileSystemResource file) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

and then inject it in your TempProcessorImpl class. Then you can run the Spring app:

```
java -jar -Dfile=/Users/some/file.txt yourapp.jar
```

P.S. you can use String or some another data type instead of FileSystemResource, depends on what is better for this task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @andrey4623. However i already have a static which is read. I have several processor bean for each fields (file has data similiar to csv) hence trying to create bean based on args which represent a field in this static file.